# Is that islam give the permission to women of coeducation?

Tags: islamic-basis, hijab, education

Is that islam give permission to women of coeducation.If they wear hijab or burka and avoid interaction with males then what islam suggest.

Comment: Are you asking on whether learning in a mixed gender environment is permissible?

Answer (score 1):

It is permissible if there is a partition and separate entrances, or if the men and women sit in different rows, so the men can not see or intermingle with the women.

Sahih Muslim 440:

> The best rows for men are the first rows, and the worst ones the last
>   ones, and the best rows for women are the last ones and the worst ones
>   for them are the first ones.

Sahih Bukhari 837:

> Whenever Allah's Messenger (SAW) finished his prayers with Taslim, the
>   women would get up and he would stay on for a while in his place
>   before getting up. Ibn Shihab said, "I think (and Allah knows better),
>   that the purpose of his stay was that the women might leave before the
>   men who had finished their prayer. "

Comment: Both evidences quoted are only tangentially relevant.